# Converting a complex json format to C# class for Highchart Organization Chart

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm trying to achieve Highcharts JSON data format for Organization chart (organogram) which indeed an inverted Sankey chart as well for my asp.net MVC project. The `series` property of the chart mainly holds the data, nodes and levels information. I'm not getting such complex JSON format examples on StackOverflow or elsewhere. The JSON structure excerpt as following -

```
{
//Some other Highcharts properties
series: [
 data: [
      ['Board', 'CEO'],
      ['CEO', 'CTO'],
      ['CEO', 'CMO'],
      ['CEO', 'HR'],
      ['CTO', 'Product'],
      ['CTO', 'Web'],
      ['CMO', 'Market']
 ],
 levels:[
      {
      level: 0,
      color: 'silver',
      dataLabels: {
        color: 'black'
      },
      height: 25
    }, 
    {
      level: 1,
      color: 'silver',
      dataLabels: {
        color: 'black'
      },
      height: 25
    }
//..more
 ],
 nodes:[
    {
      id: 'CEO',
      title: 'CEO',
      name: 'Grethe Hjetland',
      image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132317/Grethe.jpg'
    }, 
    {
      id: 'HR',
      title: 'HR/CFO',
      name: 'Anne Jorunn Fjærestad',
      color: '#007ad0',
      image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132314/AnneJorunn.jpg',
      column: 3,
      offset: '80%'
    }, 
    {
      id: 'CTO',
      title: 'CTO',
      name: 'Christer Vasseng',
      column: 4,
      image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12140620/Christer.jpg',
      layout: 'hanging'
    }
//..more
 ]
]
//Rest of the Highcharts properties
}
```

You can check for Highcharts docs- 
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/organization-chart

Mainly I've problems with `data` array property of `series`. Will jagged array work in this scenario? The `levels` and `nodes` property, I guess, will be an array of the object list. So finally how can I achieve this goal with implementation in the razor view page?

Comment: Hi @quasar, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a jagged array?

> A jagged array is an array whose elements are arrays.

This is just a list of strings for each of the data items, which  would cover most of your problems.

The json object is not complex. You will just have to create a C# class for each of the different json data types in your structure.

Something like the following.

```
public class Highchart {
    public List<Series> series;
}

public class Series {
    public List<string> data;
    public List<Level> levels;
    // etc for the rest
}

public class Level {
    // The level properties here.
}

// The same for all objects
```

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Yes it makes sense. I'll update if your example works. Thanks